# Indicador no R condicionado a variáveis com valores duplicados

Tags: r, dplyr

Suponha que existe uma base com duas variáveis como segue:

```
Município   IF
RIOBOM  Cooperativa
RIOBOM  Cooperativa
ABADIA  Múltiplo
ABADIA  Múltiplo
ABADIA  Cooperativa
ABADIA  Banco
DOURADOS    Banco
DOURADOS    Múltiplo
DOURADOS    Banco
DOURADOS    Cooperativa
DOURADOS    Múltiplo
```

Como criar um indicador que marque apenas aqueles municípios que possuem apenas "cooperativa", independente de possuir "cooperativa" e "banco" ou "múltiplo", é necessário que possua apenas "cooperativa" na variável IF.
Resultando na seguinte base:

```
Município   IF  Indicador
RIOBOM  Cooperativa 1
RIOBOM  Cooperativa 1    
ABADIA  Múltiplo    0
ABADIA  Múltiplo    0
ABADIA  Cooperativa 0
ABADIA  Banco   0
DOURADOS    Banco   0
DOURADOS    Múltiplo    0
DOURADOS    Banco   0
DOURADOS    Cooperativa 0
DOURADOS    Múltiplo    0
```

Acredito que o pacote dplyr funciona em um caso desse tipo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se existe uma forma mais direta, mas o código abaixo resolve o seu problema.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Município) %>% 
  mutate(Indicador = ifelse(IF == "Cooperativa", 1, 2)) %>% 
  mutate(Indicador = ifelse(mean(Indicador) != 1, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso!

Answer (score 3):

Agora que já está respondido e foi aceite talvez não tenha importância mas aqui vai.
Só com R base, podemos usar `ave`.

```
df$Indicador <- as.integer(ave(df$IF, df$Município, FUN = function(x)
                    all(tolower(x) == "cooperativa")) == "TRUE")
```