# Indicador no R com mais de uma condição com valores duplicados

Tags: r, dplyr

Suponha que existe uma base com duas variáveis como segue:

```
Município   IF
RIOBOM  Cooperativa
RIOBOM  Cooperativa
ABADIA  Múltiplo
ABADIA  Múltiplo
ABADIA  Cooperativa
ABADIA  Banco
DOURADOS    Banco
DOURADOS    Múltiplo
DOURADOS    Banco
DOURADOS    Cooperativa
DOURADOS    Múltiplo
```

Como criar um indicador que marque apenas aqueles municípios que possuem apenas "cooperativa" e "banco" e não possua "múltiplo". Resultando na seguinte base:

```
Município   IF  Indicador
RIOBOM  Cooperativa 0
RIOBOM  Cooperativa 0    
ABADIA  Múltiplo    0
ABADIA  Múltiplo    0
ABADIA  Cooperativa 0
ABADIA  Banco   0
DOURADOS    Banco   0
DOURADOS    Cooperativa    1
DOURADOS    Banco   0
```

Fiz uma pergunta parecida mas apenas com uma condicional, e a solução encontrada foi com a média do indicador agrupado:

[Indicador no R condicionado a variáveis com valores duplicados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256127/indicador-no-r-condicionado-a-vari%C3%A1veis-com-valores-duplicados)

Comment: Fiquei um pouco confuso com a sua pergunta. O município de DOURADOS não deveria ter o marcador 1 em todas as linhas?

Comment: O mesmo para o município de RIOBOM.

Answer (score 3):

Se a descrição do problema está correta e o exemplo de resultado esperado não, o seguinte código resolve a questão.

```
i1 <- grepl("Cooperativa|Banco", dados$IF, ignore.case = TRUE)
i2 <- !grepl("Múltiplo", dados$IF, ignore.case = TRUE)
dados$Indicador <- ave(i1 & i2, dados$Município, FUN = all) + 0L

dados
#   Município          IF Indicador
#1     RIOBOM Cooperativa         1
#2     RIOBOM Cooperativa         1
#3     ABADIA    Múltiplo         0
#4     ABADIA    Múltiplo         0
#5     ABADIA Cooperativa         0
#6     ABADIA       Banco         0
#7   DOURADOS       Banco         0
#8   DOURADOS    Múltiplo         0
#9   DOURADOS       Banco         0
#10  DOURADOS Cooperativa         0
#11  DOURADOS    Múltiplo         0
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, o Município de ABADIA teria o indicador 0 pois possui Múltiplo. Eu acho que ele quer que o Indicador seja 1 para os municípios que tiverem apenas (e ambos) Cooperativa e Banco

Comment: @RafaelCunha Obrigado, corrigido.

Answer (score 2):

Assim como o Rui disse, o seu banco de dados de origem é diferente do banco de dados com o resultado esperado. Além disso, eu tive um entendimento diferente pois acho que o município de `RIOBOM` teria o indicador `0` pois ele só possui `Cooperativa`. Dessa forma, segue código que responde a tal problema:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Município = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABADIA", "DOURADOS", "RIOBOM"), class = "factor"), 
IF = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Banco", 
"Cooperativa", "Múltiplo"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Município", 
"IF"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  group_by(Município) %>% 
  mutate(Indicador = ifelse( (any(IF == "Cooperativa") & any(IF == "Banco") & !any(IF == "Múltiplo")), 1, 0))
```

Resposta baseada nessa [dúvida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225304/filter-by-combination-of-row-pairs#48225807) do SO.